# Random line appears when div is clicked

Tags: html, css

I am wondering why is that when I double click my div a random line occurs

[image]

when I double click the black button in the middle this happens:
[image]

Why is it happening? I am guessing that is the div border?

Comment: please do more than just posting images, show some code, what you've tried, anything... this is not a real question.

Comment: You're selecting elements in your browser, and it's showing you the selection.

Comment: I think we need to see your markup and CSS before this can be answered.

Answer (score 4):

That's actually the element being selected. Double-click on text is a shortcut for "select this word".

Comment: and the OP is obviously using a huge `line-height` (*actually i am guessing that is a `.` in huge `font-size`*)